# How open PowerShell as administrator from the run window

Tags: windows, powershell, windows-10

Is possible open a new PowerShell console as administrator through the run window, in Windows?

I know that just typing 'powershell' in the run window is enough to start a new console, but is there a parameter to start it 'as Administrator'?

Like:

```
"powershell /runas:Administrator"
```

or something?

PS: I'm using Windows 10 -- I don't know if makes any difference.

Comment: Potential cross site duplicate: http://superuser.com/questions/42537/is-there-any-sudo-command-for-windows

Comment: There's a "Powershell (Admin)" option in the right-click menu on the start button...

Comment: Here's one way to open powershell (or run any command) as admin: press the Windows key (or control-escape) to bring up the Start Menu.  Type the command you want to run.  Press Control-Shift-ENTER.

Comment: @ThomasWeller: It looks like Windows 10 has some additional options for this.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

The easiest way to open an admin Powershell window in Windows 10 (and Windows 8) is to add a "Windows Powershell (Admin)" option to the "Power User Menu". Once this is done, you can open an admin powershell window via <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd>,<kbd>A</kbd> or by right-clicking on the start button and selecting "Windows Powershell (Admin)":

[[image: Windows 10/Windows 8 Power User menu with "Windows Powershell (Admin)]

Here's where you replace the "Command Prompt" option with a "Windows Powershell" option:

[[image: Taskbar and Start Menu Properties: "Replace Command Prompt With Windows Powershell"]

Comment: It was not exactly what I was expecting but, I guess it was better than what I expected -- one keypress less. I moved from win7 to 10 directly and didn't know about this "super user taskbar" stuff. Thanks, man :)

Comment: Good Reference. Does `X` implies `X` - `Windowing System` by any chance as there are `X` series mobile releases that are compatible with Linux variant,— `Android` wherein `XL` not!

Answer (score 18):

Yes, it is possible to run PowerShell through the run window. However, it would be burdensome and you will need to enter in the password for computer. This is similar to how you will need to set up when you run cmd:

```
runas /user:(ComputerName)\(local admin) powershell.exe
```

So a basic example would be:

```
runas /user:MyLaptop\AMicrosoftAccount@outlook.com  powershell.exe
```

You can find more information on this subject in *[Runas](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490994.aspx)*.

However, you could also do one more thing :

- 1: `Windows+R`
- 2: type: `powershell`
- 3: type: `Start-Process powershell -verb runAs`

then your system will execute the elevated powershell.

Comment: Last method works great.

Comment: @LuisArtola all methods do work

Answer (score 4):

Windows 10 appears to have a keyboard shortcut. According to [How to open elevated command prompt in Windows 10](https://winaero.com/blog/how-to-open-elevated-command-prompt-in-windows-10/) you can press ctrl + shift + enter from the search or start menu after typing `cmd` for the search term.

[image: image of win 10 start menu]
<sub>(source: [winaero.com](http://winaero.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2014/10/Start-menu-elevated-600x492.png))</sub>

Comment: If you just want an elevated command prompt, you can do it even more easily: Windows+X, A.

Comment: ... And if you replace the command prompt with Powershell as per my answer above, Win+X,A will open an admin PowerShell instead. This is probably the fastest solution.